# Confusing error message from calling DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Below is the second half of my code where i call DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit learn, but i am getting this error: Y_pred = DecisionTreeClassifier.predict(x_test)
TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X' . Can't make sense of why i would get this error message, since i am clearly calling x.

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=100)

model.fit(x_train,y_train)

scores = cross_val_score(model, x_train,y_train, cv=10)
print('mean: {:.3f} (std: {:.3f})'.format(scores.mean(), scores.std()), end='\n\n')

#make prediction
Y_pred = DecisionTreeClassifier.predict(x_test)

acc_train = accuracy_score(train[y_train],Y_pred)
print ('Train Accuracy: %f'%acc_train)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DecisionTreeClassifier` is a class. To use it, you  need to instantiate a class instance. You did this in the first line of your code: `model = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=100)`. Now, you need to use this instance (i.e. `model`), which you trained it on the training data, for prediction:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Indeed, Thanks alot

Comment: It would be valuable to explain what OP did and why it did not raise an parsing error, to make it more clear (as he clearly is not an experienced Python developer) so people will avoid these kind of mistakes in the future.